# Divisores de un número en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

Estaba implementando un módulo el cuál complete la clase para convertirla en un iterador que devuelva, uno por uno y en orden ascendente, todos los divisores de un número entero positivo.

Lo he intentado de la siguiente forma pero no lo consigo:

```
class Divisores:

    def __init__(self, number):

        if type(number) == int and number > 0:
            self.__number = number
        else:
            raise ValueError("Initalization parameter must be a positive integer")

    def Divisores(number):
        for i in number:
            if number % i == 0:
                yield i
```

Answer (score 1):

No puedes iterar `number` puesto que es un entero. Usa `range` en su lugar.
Algo asi:

```
class Divisores:

    def __init__(self, number):

        if type(number) == int and number > 0:
            self.__number = number
        else:
            raise ValueError("Initalization parameter must be a positive integer")

    def Divisores(self):
        number = self.__number
        for i in range(1, number+1):
            if number % i == 0:
                yield i

a = Divisores(10)
for n in a.Divisores():
    print(n)
1
2
5
10
```

Answer (score -1):

esta mal

es asi

```
valor = random.random()

valor = int(valor*5000)+1

print("el valor aleatorio es el", valor)

#calcular
while  valor > 1:

    if(valor%2 == 0):

        valor = valor / 2

        print(valor)

    else:

        valor = (valor * 3) + 1

        print(valor)
```

Comment: 1) El código no itera. 2) El código corregido implementa la conjetura de Collantz, que no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta. ¿Revisaste los resultados antes de publicar?